# Spark Sql Aggregation from cassandra

Tags: sql, apache-spark, cassandra

this is my query written for mysql database,

```
SELECT dcm.user, du.full_name, ROUND(AVG(fcg.final)) ,ROUND(AVG(fcg.participation))
FROM dimclassmem dcm LEFT JOIN factGlobal fcg on fcg.class_id=dcm.class_id GROUP BY dcm.user ORDER BY dcm.user
```

i can run this using **java + mysql**.
now i want to write this query using Spark Sql.
How can i write Aggregate function in Spark.

I am fetching data from Cassandra table , and perform simple query & it below code works,

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
val sc = new SparkContext("local", "Cassandra Connector Test", conf)

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext
.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
.options(Map("keyspace" -> "Sample", "table" -> "testTable"))
.load()

df.registerTempTable("testTable")

val ddf = sqlContext.sql("select name from testTable order by name desc limit 10")

ddf.show()
```

but , if i used follwing code it won't work,

```
val countallRec = sqlContext.sql("Select count(name) from testTable")
countallRec.show()
```

i am getting below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/rdd/MapPartitionsWithPreparationRDD
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregate.doExecute(TungstenAggregate.scala:69)
```

I want to run above query Using Spark Sql, How can i do it?

Comment: Looks like a classpath error. The spark live aren't on the cp or you may have a version mismatch. How are you launching your Application

Comment: simple scala app ..running through eclipse

Comment: So you aren't using Spark Submit? Definitely a ClassPath mismatch.